# ¿Cómo puedo sacar datos de un SELECT y luego hacer INSERT en un bucle con PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access

Básicamente tengo un problema de lógica. Tengo dos BBDD, una MySQL y otra MS Access. Ya he desarrollado un algoritmo que me diga qué IdPedido de MySQL no está en la BBDD de MS Access. Por tanto, ahora tengo un array dónde almaceno esos IdPedido. Imaginemos lo siguiente:

```
$datos=[1234-Y, 2345-L, 3456-O];
```

Bien, ahora necesito:

1º) Recorrer el array con los IdPedido.
2º) Hacer una consulta a la base de datos de MySQL con los IDPedidos para sacar todos los datos (supongamos que los datos son Nombre, Direccion, Ciudad y Precio) del registro.
3º) Una vez realizada esa consulta, con todos esos datos, hacer un INSERT en la otra BBDD.
4º) Pasar al siguiente registro.

El caso es que estoy liado porque:

a) No sé llevar esto a código, ni si la lógica es la más adecuada. ¿Metería esas varias consultas en un bucle while que recorra dicho array? 
b) ¿Se supone que debería guardar los datos de la consulta en una variable PHP de tipo array, y luego anidar otro while que me recorra dicho array para sacarme los datos de dicha variable a fin de poder hacer el INSERT?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: No te entendí bien o te liaste en el punto 4º. Lo más simple sería hacer la consulta a Base de Datos `A`, sacar de ella los datos que serían insertados en Base de Datos `B`. Cuando tengas los datos de `A`, te olvidas de ella, y ahora abres una conexión a `B` y usas la variable donde guardaste los datos de `A` y haces el `INSERT` en `B`.

Comment: O sea, punto por punto: (1) Conectar a `A`, hacer la consulta, guardar los datos en `$fromA` y cerrar la conexión a `A`; (2) Conectar a `B` y lanzar una consulta `INSERT` usando los datos que tienes en `$fromA`. ...Fin de la historia... Eso es mucho más lógico y sencillo que tener dos conexiones en paralelo leyendo e insertando constantemente. Como recomendación, sería bueno que uses transacciones en el punto `(2)` antes dicho.

Comment: A ver, el tema que para hacer la consulta primera, necesito ir recorriendo un array ($dbChanges) para sacar el IdPedido que metería en el WHERE. Es decir: SELECT x, y, z from Pedidos WHERE IdPedido=$IdPedido. Ese IdPedido lo tengo que ir sacando recorriendo el array. El tema es que no sé aquí que es mejor. Guardo en un array todos los registros completos y luego lo recorro para insertar, o lo voy haciendo registro a registro, es decir, guardo registroA y procedo a INSERTAR? En ese caso, tendría que meter todo ese código y luego ir repitiendo el proceso. ¿Qué sería más óptimo?

Comment: Me remito a mi anterior comentario.  (1) Conectas a `A` y escribes una sola consulta parecida a esto: `SELECT * FROM laTabla WHERE IdProducto IN($mIDs);` esa consulta te traerá todos los registros que haya en tu array de IDs, para crear `$mIDs` deberás usar `implode` para que te cree una lista separada por comas con todos los IDs. Seguidamente lees los resultados en un `while` y los vas guardando en `$fromA`, luego cierras esa conexión; (2) Abres la conexión a `B` y haces el `INSERT` con los datos que ya tienes en `$fromA`. ...Fin de la historia... ¿Hay algo que no entiendes de todo lo dicho?

Comment: No comprendo por qué crear un array con los IDs, si precisamente dicho array ya lo tengo. Es decir, yo ahora mismo tengo que hacer un SELECT para sacar todos los datos de cada registro, y entiendo que dices que dichos datos los meto en una variable de tipo matriz. Y que cuando tenga todos, cierre conexión con A, abra conexión con B, recorra matriz con todos los datos e inserte. ¿Esa sería la lógica?

Comment: Sí, pero no te he dicho que crees un array con los IDs, sino que uses `implode` para crear a partir del array de IDs que ya tienes una lista separada por comas y puedas usarla para traer todos los datos en una sola consulta usando `IN($mIDs)` donde `$mIDS` sería algo como esto: `'234-Y', '2345-L', '3456-O'`, así no tienes que leer el array mandando un `SELECT WHERE` por cada valor. A eso me refería con lo del `implode`

Comment: Genial, ni siquiera sabía que se podía hacer eso. Investigo para hacerlo, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sabiendo (por otras preguntas) que los datos del `SELECT` estarían en un SGBD y que el `INSERT`tendría que hacerse en otro SGDB distinto, podrías hacer esto:

### A.

En primer lugar preparas tu contenido en `$datos` para poder usarlos en una consulta usando `IN()` como criterio en el `WHERE`. Así evitas hacer un `SELECT` por cada valor.

```
$datos=['1234-Y', '2345-L', '3456-O'];
$mIDs= "'".implode("','", $datos)."'";
```

Ahora puedes lanzar la consulta usando `$mIDs` que tendrá algo como esto: `'1234-Y','2345-L','3456-O'`

```
#Aquí la conexión a la 1ª BD se llamará $conA
$sql="SELECT * FROM laTabla WHERE IdProducto IN($mIDs)";
$mDataA=mysqli_query($conA, $sql);
#Array que contendrá los datos encontrados
$fromA=array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mDataA)){
    #Llenamos el array con cada valor de $row
    $fromA[] = $row;
}
#Cerramos la conexión
$conA=null;
```

---

### B.

Creas una nueva conexión al otro SGBD y usas `$fromA` para hacer la inserción.

En este punto te hago algunas recomendaciones, si tienes dudas puedes preguntar en comentarios o abrir otra pregunta según el caso:

- Para evitar varias llamadas a `mysqli_query()` para insertar cada fila que haya en `$fromA` podrías armar una sola consulta de inserción, algo así:

  ```
   INSERT INTO laNuevaTabla 
       (colA, colB, colC, colD) 
   VALUES 
       ('f1C1','f1C2','f1C3','f1C4'),
       ('f2C1','f2C2','f2C3','f2C4'),
       ('f3C1','f3C2','f3C3','f3C4'),
       ('f4C1','f4C2','f4C3','f4C4'),

   ... etc
  ```

  Armando la columna así estarías ejecutando una sola consulta de inserción con múltiples valores, no múltiples consultas de inserción, ganando en rendimiento.
- Cuando se insertan/modifican datos masivos en las tablas se recomienda usar transacciones, para controlar cualquier fallo y poder revertir los cambios antes de confirmarlos. Esto es particularmente útil cuando alguna de las inserciones fallan y no podrías saber cuál falló, teniendo que determinar luego con mucho trabajo qué datos se insertaron y que datos faltan por insertar.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Dos dudas: -"SELECT * FROM laTabla WHERE IdProducto IN($mIDs)"; $mIDs es un array con varios IDs, ¿de esta forma te ahorras el bucle y sacas todos los IDs juntos de una? -¿Cuándo insertas en una nueva tabla, cómo sabes que estás insertando f2c1 y no f1c5? Mil gracias. Por cierto, que estoy releyendo, ¿Cómo preparo el $datos para poder hacer la consulta? Lo pregunto porque no son siempre los mismos datos, es el IDPedido del registro que está en una tabla y en la otra no. A veces será un id, otras veces varios, y siempre serán diferentes.

Comment: @Sergio `$mIDs` será la lista de IDs que necesitas en `A` para saber qué filas son las que necesitas recuperar. Luego guardarás cada fila en `$fromA` que será un array con cada fila/columna  de los resultados y será eso lo que insertarás en `B`. Leyendo a `$fromA` podrás construir un solo `INSERT`, pero no hay riesgo de que los datos queden dislocados, pues se habrán metido por fila cuando los recuperaste en `A`.